# Question about Ito Process. Stochastic Processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

How to prove, that $W_{t/(1-t)}$ at $[0,1)$ is Ito Process ? (Have stohastic differential)

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stackexchange. You'll get more help if you provide context and show us what you have tried.

Comment: I tried check by the definition, but i have no results. Maybe someone can help me getting started

Answer (score 0):

You justo have to solve $W_{\frac{t}{1-t}}=\int_0^t b_sdB_s$, if i'm not mistaken with the calculations, you first must get with Ito's isometry that $b_s=1/(1-s)$, then you get $B_t=\int_0^t b_s^{-1}dW_{\frac{s}{1-s}}=\int_0^{\frac{t}{1-t}}\frac{dW_s}{(1+s)^2}$, this is a Brownian Motion because Levy's Characterization Criterion apply. So you can ensure that $$W_{\frac{t}{1-t}}=\int_0^t \frac{dB_s}{1-s},\qquad t\in[0,1).$$

Comment: It’s not clear how we get last integral

Comment: It's because you have that $dW_{\frac{t}{1-t}}=\frac{dB_t}{1-t}\; \Leftrightarrow\; (1-t)dW_{\frac{t}{1-t}}=dB_t \; \Leftrightarrow\; B_t=\int_0^t(1-s)dW_{\frac{s}{1-s}} $

Comment: Okay, it’s clear thank you!

Comment: And could you please say how we get $b_s$? I still don’t understand how we get 1/(1-s)

Comment: Of course, ito's isometry (and I  assumed that $W$ is a brownian motion) tells you that $\frac{t}{1-t}=\mathbb{E}[W_{\frac{t}{1-t}}^2]=\mathbb{E}[\left(\int_0^t b_s dB_s \right)^2]=\int_0^t b_s^2 ds$ after deriving you get that $\frac{d}{dt} \frac{t}{1-t} =1/(1-t)^2=b_t^2$

Comment: Okay, I see, thank you!